# Samsung Galaxy S Camera problem

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera

When taking pictures with the Samsung Galaxy S's camera I get a rather large red spot in from the center of the image outwards. I've uploaded an image showing this.

[image: Image showing problem with red spot]

Comment: I just bought my Samsung Galaxy S2, also has a same problem. I just changed it at the shop and the problem is still there. I think there is no solution over the RED SPOT issue. I love SGS2 but it's a shame for such a poor quality made from Samsung.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same problem here in Brazil. Last year, I bought a Galaxy S, and the photos had that red color in the center. I went to the store and exchanged it for another one, which had the same problem. I went to the store and returned it. I decided for an iPhone 4. Now, I got bored with iPhone 4 and this week I bought another Galaxy S, it has the same problem (red color in the center of the photo), but I decided to keep it anyway.

For what I see in your post, the red color is a general problem. I just don’t understand why the Samsung has not already corrected that problem.

I have made some tests with the camera, and noticed that the problem occurs in low light conditions, especially under incandescent light, but outdoors the picture is normal.

Maybe the problem could be correct by some software or an update for Samsung.

I looked over in the internet and didn’t find any solution.

So, if somebody knows a solution, please post it here.

Comment: +1 for 'got bored with iPhone4'  :) .  No really, +1 for the extra testing part.

Comment: Hi, Nogueira. Thank you for your input. I saw that it only happens in low light conditions and if you look at the glass protecting the camera from a certain angle, you will see a red tint to it. I think it's a physical problem rather than a software one. Where I live we are yet to receive 2.3, but I'll wait until then. Thanks again.

Comment: I did a mistake in my post. The red tint appears under low light, especially under **incandescent** light.

Comment: @Nogueira I edited your post after reading your comment. As an FYI you can always edit your own posts, rather than put the edits in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the phone to where ever you bought it from and have them take a look at it. It's most likely some sort of hardware issue that they will be able to take care of.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that then. I just wanted to make sure there is no software issue first or something that I was missing. Thank you, Adam.

Answer (score 1):

It is a hardware fault and it may be unlikely you will find one without it I have only seen one that did not have the issue and it was an early sample. Returned several myself then got my money back Samsung should issue a public statement about this as the camera part of the phone is not fit for its purpose with this fault. probably best to get your money back and wait until Samsung come clean about what is going on with this issue. If you do decide to get a different phone with an 8mpix camera do check it out before buying as it could be to do with the sensor supplier and the same sensor may be used in other phones